# popup menu when mouse hovers on the button in the appbar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, popup, appbar

Microsoft suggests putting all the commands in the bottom appbar, I want to display a popup menu for detail command when my mouse hover on the button of the appbar, and after mouse move from the button, the popup menu disappears. After searching for a long time, still don't find a solution, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Context menu control](http://csell.net/2012/11/16/31-days-of-windows-8-day-16-context-menus/)

But Windows 8 is also system for tablet's and touch devices so event OnMouseOver is not good way. Better handle the Right Click Event.